# Android Kotlin Firebase real time database: RecyclerView Shows Empty

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have read all similar questions however could not find a solution. There is not any error.

Could you please see these codes and help to find the problem why these codes do not show data from Firebase. Is there any problem with the query? or RecyclerView? or adapter?

```
class OurResults : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_allresults)
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar))

        BeginFirebaseAuthListener()
        Beginsicknesslistener()
    }

    var mValueEventListener:ValueEventListener=object :ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            BringSickness()
        }
    }

    private fun BringSickness() {
        if(allsickness==null){
            allsickness=ArrayList<usersickness>()
        }
        mySicknessReferans=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        var userid=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
        var myQuery=mySicknessReferans?.child("sickness/users/$user_id"+"/")!!
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("not implemented")
                }
                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    for(Onesickness in p0!!.children){
                        var tempsickness=usersickness()  
                        tempsickness.photo_result=Onesickness.getValue(usersickness::class.java)!!.photo_result
                        tempsickness.date=Onesickness.getValue(usersickness::class.java)!!.date
                        allsickness?.add(tempsickness)
                        myAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            })
        if(myAdapter==null){
            initsicknesslist()
        }
    }

    private fun initsicknesslist() {
        myAdapter= SicknessRecyclerViewAdapter(this,allsickness!!)
        rv_sickness.adapter=myAdapter
        rv_sickness.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        rv_sickness.scrollToPosition(myAdapter?.itemCount!!-1)
    }

    private fun Beginsicknesslistener() {
        mySicknessReferans=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("sickness/users/"+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid)
        mySicknessReferans?.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener)
    }

    private fun BeginFirebaseAuthListener() {
        mAuthListener=object:FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener{
            override fun onAuthStateChanged(p0: FirebaseAuth) {
                var myUser=p0.currentUser
                if(myUser==null){
                    var intent=Intent(this@allresults,LoginActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener (mAuthListener!!)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if(mAuthListener!=null){
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener (mAuthListener!!)
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
    }

}
```

**The database structure is:**
    --user
       - xGKiiLnf6TWhJeThkeKbZxtwHr1 
          -email:
          -photo:
          -userid:
       - gYJMhNRZ5XPMzAROsoNyQOmdVFd2
          -email:
          -photo:
          -userid:
    --sickness
       - users
            -gYJMhNRZ5XPMzAROsoNyQOmdVFd2
                 -184b4d0f-9cd3-413b-b4ed-3b6485066
                     -date:
                     -photo_id:

Comment: Can you add your database structure?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: When a user login to the app, his/her data sickness information from data should be presented on the screen. However, the screen is empty. These codes do not give error but do not show any information of the user.

Comment: --user
   - gYJMhNRZ5XPMzAROsoNyQOmdVFd2
      -email:
      -photo:
      - userid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Da8.png)**First of all,** your `ValueEventListener` is redundant. So, no need to call `Beginsicknesslistener` instead call `BringSickness` from `onCreate`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    .....

    BeginFirebaseAuthListener()
    //Beginsicknesslistener()

    BringSickness()
}
```

**And then** parse the sickness data inside `BringSickness` like below:

```
private fun BringSickness() {
    if(allsickness == null){
        allsickness = ArrayList<usersickness>()
    }

    if(myAdapter == null){
        initsicknesslist()
    }

    mySicknessReferans = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    var userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
    var myQuery = mySicknessReferans?.child("sickness/users/$user_id"+"/")!!
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented")
            }
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                for(Onesickness in p0!!.children){
                    var tempsickness = Onesickness.getValue(usersickness::class.java)

                    if(tempsickness != null) {
                        allsickness?.add(tempsickness)
                    }
                }

                //Update adapter after collecting all the data
                myAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        })

}
```

**Suggestion:** You should follow [standard naming convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules) during coding.